# Can't use code example from dlang.org

Tags: d

I have code which doesn't compile

```
import std.string;
import std.net.curl;

int main(string[] argv)
{
    string a = get("http://google.com");
    return 0;
}

Error: cannot implicitly convert expression (get("http://google.com", AutoProtocol())) of type char[] to string
```

And in http://dlang.org/phobos/std_net_curl.html there is code

```
import std.net.curl, std.stdio;

// Return a string containing the content specified by an URL
string content = get("dlang.org");
```

Why can't I compile the same code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The example is wrong - get returns char[] instead of string. The difference is a string is immutable, but a char isn't.

Two ways to fix it:

```
char[] a = get("http://google.com"); // or you could do auto a = ... instead
```

or

```
string a = get("http://google.com").idup;
```

The second one makes an immutable copy of the data. The first one uses the appropriate type.

Comment: I would recommend the generic std.conv.to!string over .idup. Personal preference I supose.